# ViewModel's exposed data depends on size of the View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

## Background

I am a beginner WPF developer. As a learning exercise I am attempting to recreate Visual Studio's Memory window using WPF with the MVVM pattern. For those of you unfamiliar with this window.

[image]

## Implementation Outline

For simplicity we assume the memory is readonly and will not change. As per the MVVM pattern we define the following entities:

### Model

The **Model** is a simple object that contains 2 properties:

1. `long Address`

   - Address of where the Data resides in memory
2. `byte[] Data`

The **Model** represents a sequence of bytes (`Data`) at a defined memory address (`Address`).

### ViewModel

The **ViewModel** takes the **Model** as input and exposes the following properties:

1. `string Addresses`

   - A `string` representing the addresses of the bytes displayed on the same row. Referencing the image in the **Background** section, the `Addresses` `string` contains the contents of the first column, that is:

     `string Addresses = "0x022699B0" + '\n' +
                         "0x022699C8" + '\n' +
                         "0x022699E0" + '\n' +
                          ...`
2. `string HexBytes`

   - A hexadecimal representation of the `Data` in the **Model**. Referencing the image in the **Background** section, the `HexBytes` `string` contains the contents of the second column, that is:

     `string HexBytes = "c0 ac 45 68 06 ..."`
3. `string ASCIIBytes`

   - An ASCII representation of the `Data` in the **Model**. Referencing the image in the **Background** section, the `ASCIIBytes` `string` contains the contents of the third column, that is:

     `string ASCIIBytes = "A.Ch....9.1.1.1.2.5 ..."`

To summarize, the **ViewModel** exposes the data given my the **Model** in a **View** friendly format.

### View

The **View** is probably easiest to describe via an XAML code snippet:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HexEditor.HexView"
         xmlns  ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:z="clr-namespace:HexEditor">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <z:MemoryViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Arrow" FontFamily="Consolas" Text="{Binding Addresses, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Cursor="Arrow" FontFamily="Consolas" Text="{Binding HexBytes, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Cursor="Arrow" FontFamily="Consolas" Text="{Binding ASCIIBytes, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Notice the `TextWrapping` attribute has been set on the second and third columns. This allows us to display a variable number of bytes per row, depending on the size of the Window.

## Problem

The problem I am encountering is that the properties the **ViewModel** must expose depend on the size of the **View**. In the MVVM pattern, the **ViewModel** should be independent of the **View**. This is not a problem for `HexBytes` and `ASCIIBytes` as these are generated from the **Model**. The problem is how to generate the `Addresses`? To generate this `string` I must know the number of characters that will be displayed on each line (so that I can calculate the correct address of the first byte of the next line). This is unfortunately something only the **View** knows about, as it depends on the size of the **View**.

## Proposed Solution

My attempt to solve this problem is to capture the `SizeChanged` events in the **View** code-behind and use the `TextBox.GetLineLength` method to inform the **ViewModel** of how many bytes can fit on a line. The **ViewModel** can then consume this value to generate the correct `Addresses` property.

## Discussion

I have two questions regarding my proposed solution:

1. Is there a more elegant way of informing the **ViewModel** on the number of characters that can be displayed on 1 line of the second `TextBox`?
2. Am I using the correct Controls and the correct approach more importantly to get to my end result (i.e. recreating the Memory Window of Visual Studio)?

Thanks so much for any input or comments.

Comment: Your view could call 'UpdateLayout' when you generate these properties. HTH.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, the problem is how to generate the properties in the first place? **ViewModel** must somehow know how to generate the `Addresses` string without being aware of the **View**.

Comment: don't know if I understand this question correctly, English is not my first language, but if you want to generate the data based on the number of characters in your `view` which _de_ _facto_ are coming from `Model` your `VM` shouldn't have any problems retrieving that info from Model? or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I think you may be misunderstanding. Sure the data comes from the `Model`, but the `ViewModel` must transform that data so the `View` can consume it. This requires me to generate the `Addresses` string. If the `View` is stretched (or the size is changed in general) then the number of bytes that can fit on one line changes as well. This means that we must update the `Addresses` to match so an address on a specific line corresponds to the first byte on the same line.

Comment: I see. You can keep `Address` and `Hex` or `ASCII` together by using `DataTemplate` that will keep them together no matter what size of the view.  
Then you need to derive from a `Control` like `Panel` or whichever control suits your needs and `override` the `Measure` method. [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) is an example of `DataTemplate`. Let me know if you need more info and I'll create simple app for you. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way of informing the ViewModel on the number of characters that can be displayed on 1 line

I think your approach is the best one.  The outcome you have in mind -- variable column width with inferred column headers -- implies a dependency of the view-model on the view.  (Some MVVM approaches use some kind of "messaging" framework (eg, event aggregators) to communicate between view and view-model, but that is just a more formalized way of having the view directly invoke a method on the view-model.)  Also, you will need to be handling the `SizeChanged` event in any case, in order to re-generate the column headers on each re-size.

> Am I using the correct Controls and the correct approach more importantly to get to my end result

It seems fine.  You might consider using an `ObservableCollection<string>` along with an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` (instead of the flat string with line breaks).  That would allow you more control over the UI, enabling things like highlighting/selection of individual addresses; synchronized scrolling of the addresses/bytes; and virtualized panels to handle larger data sets without the UI grinding down.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight. As for your answer to my second question, the reason I am trying to stay away from using `ObservableCollection`s is because I would lose the ability to select the hex bytes across multiple lines. For example, with an `ObservableCollection`, how would one select and copy 2 lines of the hex bytes? I have not tried using an `ObservableCollection`, so this may be possible without any extra plumbing? If so I will definitely take this approach.

Comment: @RichardGorrin I don't think there is a way to do that with a collection, so I guess that would require as you are doing, a string along with a TextBox/ RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1):

When you capture that value in your event handler just update the VM property that keeps this value from within that event handler and that way VM will always have that value as soon as the event fires...

Since your VM is already the `DataContext` of your view this is not breaking the MVVM pattern and updating that value of the VM property is very simple:

This is all in your View code-behind:

Field:

```
private MyViewModel vm;
```

In view constructor (or DataContextChanged event if you assign DataContext dynamically):

```
vm = DataContext as MyViewModel; //Get VM instance from view's DataContext
```

In event handler:

```
vm.AddressLenght = TextBox.GetLineLength;
```